# Python as FastCGI under windows and apache

Tags: python, windows, apache, fastcgi

I need to run a simple request/response python module under an
existing system with windows/apache/FastCGI.

All the FastCGI wrappers for python I tried work for Linux only
(they use socket.fromfd() and other such shticks).

Is there a wrapper that runs under windows?

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier to ditch FastCGI altogether and just run a python webserver on a localhost port. Then just use mod_rewrite to map the apache urls to the internal webserver.

(I started offering FastCGI at my hosting company and to my surprise, nearly everyone ditched it in favor of just running their own web server on the ports I provided them.)

Answer (score 1):

A [Django bug](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8742) suggests that [python-fastcgi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-fastcgi) will work for you, and its PyPI page reports that it works on Windows.

Comment: already tried it. the c code does not compile. if no other option, i'll dive into it, but first looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) or [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).